# Access only ExcelShapes

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, epplus

I am trying to access the CheckBoxes from my worksheet using the below shown code.

```
foreach ( OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelShape ch in xlWorkSheetinc.Drawings)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ch.Name);
}
```

Unfortunately, the code above returns `ExcelPicture` and gives an exception as shown below :

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture' to type 'OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelShape'.
```

Need some suggestions or guidance here on how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
foreach (OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing ch in xlWorkSheetinc.Drawings)
  {
    if (ch.Name.Contains("Check"))
    {
      OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelShape c = (OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelShape)ch;
    }
  }
```

This way I can access the ExcelShape's properties.
For my luck Excel has an incremental naming. So every Checkbox I create and not renaming it will look like Check Box 1, Check Box 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the type of the `Drawing` to see if it is of type `ExcelShape` rather than checking by name:

```
foreach (ExcelShape c in xlWorkSheetinc.Drawings.Where(d => d.GetType() == typeof(ExcelShape)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```

I've removed the namespace from the `ExcelShape` above so the code fits better here so you might want to replace `ExcelShape` with `OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelShape`.